# Ligação de tabelas com Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma tabela de clientes que armazena os dados pessoais, login, senha entre outros, e uma outra tabela de faturas, que tem todas as faturas de todos os clientes, porém preciso fazer a busca dos dados do cliente com um ID do usuário armazenado na tabela de faturas, como faço isso usando Code Igniter?

Aqui está parte do código que faz a busca das faturas:

```
   $query = $this->admin->get_all('faturas')->result();
            foreach ($query as $linha) {
                echo '<tr>';
                printf('<td>%s %s</td>', $linha->nome, $linha->sobrenome);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->numero);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->valor);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', ($linha->status==0) ? 'Não':'Sim');
                printf('<td class="text-center">%s%s%s</td>', 
                    anchor("admin/cliente/alterar/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-edit', 'title'=>'Editar')),
                    anchor("admin/cliente/alterar_senha/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-pass', 'title'=>'Alterar Senha')),
                    anchor("admin/cliente/excluir/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-delete deletareg', 'title'=>'Excluir'))
                    );
                echo '</tr>';
```

Resolvido assim:

```
$query = $this->admin->get_all('faturas')->result();
            foreach ($query as $linha) {
                $cliente = $this->admin->get_byid('clientes', $linha->id_cliente)->row();
                echo '<tr>';
                printf('<td>%s %s</td>', $cliente->nome,  $cliente->sobrenome);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->numero);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->valor);
                printf('<td>%s</td>', ($linha->status==0) ? 'Não':'Sim');
                printf('<td class="text-center">%s%s%s</td>', 
                    anchor("admin/cliente/alterar/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-edit', 'title'=>'Editar')),
                    anchor("admin/cliente/alterar_senha/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-pass', 'title'=>'Alterar Senha')),
                    anchor("admin/cliente/excluir/$linha->id",' ', array('class'=>'table-actions table-delete deletareg', 'title'=>'Excluir'))
                    );
                echo '</tr>';
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível com um `INNER JOIN`, no `CodeIgniter` pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
<?php 

// application/models/admin.php

public function get_faturas()
{
    $this->db->select('faturas.numero, faturas.valor, faturas.status, cliente.nome, cliente.sobrenome');
    $this->db->from('faturas');
    $this->db->join('cliente', 'faturas.id_cliente = cliente.id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: Legal Lucio, vou experimentar seu método, sou novo com CodeIgniter, então toda ajuda é bem vinda!